# A better way to import AUTH_USER_MODEL in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make plugable apps more resilient under Django 1.5 where you now have a custom definable user model.

When adding foreign keys to a model I can do:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

which saves me the import of User at the top of the file that breaks when `django.contrib.auth.models.User` is no longer the user model.  But sometimes when testing, I need to be able to create a user, and the best I've been able to come up with for this is

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import get_model
User = get_model(*settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.'))
```

then I can do things like:

```
User.objects.create(username="test")
```

within my test (some objects have FK's tied to users and I need one of those objects in a test).

It doesn't strike me as particularly elegant, but I really don't see any cleaner way to do this in 1.5.

Did I miss something in the docs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way you could do it is:

```
try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
except ImportError: # django < 1.5
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
else:
    User = get_user_model()
```

Comment: Did `get_user_model` not exist prior to 1.5?  If not, this is a very good point.

Comment: Nope - check the difference: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py and https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py

Answer (score 7):

Just remember, **`get_user_model` cannot be called at module level**. In particular, do not even think of using it in `models.py` to define a `ForeignKey` relationship. Use the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting if you have to.

Otherwise, as I have discovered, you will be getting weird and difficult-to-debug bugs where certain models just won't be available. In fact, I had a situation where just adding `print get_user_model()` to a certain file caused another import to fail, in a totally different django app.

If I read [this introduction to get_user_model](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/), I could have saved myself a few hours...

Comment: Same painful experience with code running, but sphinx-build complaining terribly. The text that helped me was in the Django manual: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model "Generally speaking, you should reference the User model with the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting in code that is executed at import time. get_user_model() only works once Django has imported all models."

Comment: As of Django 1.11, `get_user_model` can now be called at module level See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model