# Best way to reference the User model in Django >= 1.5

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the best way to reference User model in Django >= 1.5?

After reading [Referencing the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model), I've started using (1) for a while:

(1)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

But following the Zen of Python, Readability counts, why not this:

(2)

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

User = get_user_model()

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Yeah. The second is what i would go with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723525/a-better-way-to-import-auth-user-model-in-django-1-5/16723646#16723646

Comment: So, django doc's kinda sucks in this part, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### UPDATE: As of Django 1.11, [`get_user_model`  can now be called at import time, even in modules that define models.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model)

That means you could do this:
`models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), ...)`

---

Original answer (Django <= 1.11)

You might [experience circular reference](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/) issues if you use `get_user_model` at module level. Another option for importing the auth user model is:

```
from django.conf import settings

AUTH_USER_MODEL = getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', 'auth.User')

# models
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

The `getattr` will return Django's default user model, which is `auth.User`, if `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is not detected in the settings file.

Comment: I agree this is the best to avoid the circular dependency. But then, how do you write a code like `MyUser.objects.all()` after getting the AUTH_USER_MODEL?

Comment: @eugene This answer is for referencing User model only (`getattr` will return a string, not an object). You can use `get_user_model` for that case.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you just extend the user model (or don't touch it at all), you an do:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Actually this is for Django < 1.5

Answer (score 2):

I don't think "Readability counts" is about second case.

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

looks like

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

... # Imagine tons of code here    

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

for me. Will be surprised when won't work

```
article.author.get_full_name() # or any auth.models.User specific method
```

Comment: But it works! If you're using Django >= 1.5 and using AbstractBaseUser, you have to implement get_full_name()

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the second one. With the second way, you can have everything in the same file and you don't need to modify 2 different files, with the possible problems you can find with that.